# Regex doesnt match the file path in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I've spent quite some time trying to figure out why this regex doesn't match files with names like:

```
/var/tmp/app.0.attachments 
.... 
/var/tmp/app.11.attachments
```

```
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/app/\.([0-9]{1}|1[0-1]{1})/\.attachments
$: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I've tried escaping `[`, `]`, `|` and `{}`

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/app.{0..11}.attachments
```

Comment: This works well for `rm -f`. Be careful with other commands, where this will pass in all twelve file names whether or not they exist. Replace `rm -rf` with `ls`, for instance, and you'd get some errors.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes do not work at the shell. Shells do globbing, which is simpler and not as powerful. With the default globbing, the best you can do is something like:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/app/app.[0-9]*.attachments
```

If you enable extended globbing, you can add pipes and grouping to the toolset.

```
shopt -s extglob
sudo rm -rf /var/tmp/app/app.@([0-9]|1[0-1]).attachments
```

Note the different syntax. It's not regex, but it's similar. From the bash(1) man page:

> If the **extglob** shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin, several extended pattern matching operators  are  recognized.   In the  following  description,  a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a `|`.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the following sub-patterns:
>
> ```
> ?(pattern-list)
>        Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
> *(pattern-list)
>        Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
> +(pattern-list)
>        Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
> @(pattern-list)
>        Matches one of the given patterns
> !(pattern-list)
>        Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

Another alternative would be to use `find`, which can do both globbing and regexes.

```
sudo find /var/tmp -regex '/var/tmp/app\.\([0-9]\|1[0-1]\)\.attachments' -delete
sudo find /var/tmp -regex '/var/tmp/app\.\([0-9]\|1[0-1]\)\.attachments' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Note that it performs a match on the entire path, not just the file name. You also have to escape `\(`, `\)`, and `\|`.